# "cannot find symbol [method name]" although the method is declared

Tags: java, compiler-errors

The following code

```
class Matrix {
  private int[][] matrice;
  public Matrix(int[][] matrice){
    this.matrice = matrice;
  }
  public int rows(){
    return matrice.length;
  }
  public int columns(){
    return matrice[0].length;
  }
  public Matrix add(Matrix secondMatrix){
    int[][] sum = new int[matrice.rows()][matrice.columns()]; //ERROR
    Matrix result = new Matrix(sum);
    return result;
  }
}
```

Returns two errors when I declare the "sum" array as it "cannot find symbol method rows()" nor "method columns()". What could be the problem?

Comment: An `int[][]` does not have a method called `rows()`.

Comment: @user7 You're right, I was referring to "matrice" as a "Matrix" object but in reality it's an array!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should change this

From:

```
int[][] sum = new int[matrice.rows()][matrice.columns()];
```

To:

```
int[][] sum = new int[secondMatrix.rows()][secondMatrix.columns()];
```

Comment: Thank you, this fixes the problem!

Comment: And it should work even if I put int[][] sum = new int[this.rows()][this.columns()]; instead, right?

Comment: yes, `this.rows()` will get the number of rows of the current `matrice` object. And `secondMatrix.columns()` will get the number of rows of the inputted `secondMatrix`. It depends on what you want to do :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!